# the if stament it's ignored

Tags: python, function

I'm a beginner and my function doesn't work. I don't what I missed in it:

```
def string_length(stri):
if stri == int:
   print(" not a string")
else:
   print(len(stri), stri)

stri = str(input("please write a string: "))
string_length(stri)
```

in a few, the if statement it's ignored if I write an integer.

Comment: it's not that it's ignored. It's that what you think it's doing vs what it's actually doing is very different. stri == int is *not* how you check if something is *an* int.

Comment: Your "if" tests if a particular object is equal to the integer type. That doesn't make sense here. You want "isinstance".

Comment: Also, note that your inputs are always going to be strings if you're accepting them from user. "3" and 3 are different. one is a string.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def is_number(stri):
    try:
        float(stri)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        pass

def string_length(stri):
    if is_number(stri) == True:
       print(" not a string")
    else:
       print(len(stri), stri)

stri = input("please write a string: ")
is_number(stri)
string_length(stri)
```

It didn't work for you because a number can be in the form of a string, e.g "6" instead of 6. So any time you put in a number it would be a string and so would ignore the if. the is_number() function checks whether the string can be represented as a float and if so returns the value "True".